# Loade image from war

Tags: java, image, web, war

I have some troubles with loading a image out of a war file. My function for this is the following:

```
private String printResource(ResourceBean resource) throws IOException {
     URLConnection connection = getServerURL(resource.getPath()).openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
     String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
         response.append(inputLine).append("\n");
      in.close();
      return response.toString();
}
```

The return value of this function will be written directly in the webpage. My issue is the following. The image is not displayed and if I download and open it. the program tell me, that the image is invalid or damaged.

I have no idea where the problem could be, I would be really grateful for an answer.

EDIT:

I have added some changes to the function:

```
private String printResource(ResourceBean resource, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    URL url = getServerURL(resource.getPath());
    if (resource.getType().equals("pic")) {
        masterLogger.debug("Resource is a pic, special treatment");
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
        File f = new File(resource.getId());
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", f);
        FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(f);
        return fis.toString();
    } else {
        URLConnection connection = getServerURL(resource.getPath()).openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder responseText = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            responseText.append(inputLine).append("\n");
        in.close();
        return responseText.toString();
    }
}
```

Now I get a NullPointer at the ImageIO.write() line 1538.

More informaiton:

- I load a jpg from my resources in the war file
- The URL is correct, oterwise the first line would throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Example:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(connection.getInputStream());
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("downloaded_1.jpg"));
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("downloaded_2.png"));
```

or you can write to the servlet response (providing correct request and response properties) or `ByteArrayOutputStream` instance

If it's from war best way to get the path is through `ServletContext` ex: `InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(path);`

Comment: +1  An image is not textual data.  Don't use a text based `Reader` for it!

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I just implemented this in the function, but the result is still the same, the image isn't valid. I also set a different header-contenttype with the sme result.

Comment: Where do you want to read the image from ? inside the web-app or from a client? is your URL correct ? I update the answer adding more details it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I have postet my changes in the questions

Comment: What you are doing is wrong. why do you write it to a file since you want to return the binary data? Write it to a stream and get the bytes instead. Do a google search you could get loads of examples.